# Complex Sum Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Apologies if this is lame, but I can't get a proper value using `=SUM` to perform order of operations on an employees hours (he has gotten two raises since starting after surpassing expectations). The notes on the cells denotes a pay increase, the first one is a start.

I tried this formula:

`=SUM((F15*20)+(F16:F20*25)+(F21:F23*30))`

but that returns an error. What am I doing wrong to get the sum of all the hours multiplied by their correct hourly wage?

[image: sheets column]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple sums in the formula, you need multiple SUM commands, one for each sum. That is,

```
=F15*20+SUM(F16:F20)*25+SUM(F21:F23)*30
```

Have to add things up before multiplying them all by a common factor.